# How to use theme for widgets images(override images in theme) in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have own module with some icons (Modules\MyModule\Content\Images\flag.png).

Its posible to use some theme with override icons of this module/widget? Something like (Themes\MyTheme\Content\MyModule\Images\flag.png)

How to reference this on views?

Thanks for some hints.

Comment: You would have to override the view displaying the image and change the reference

Comment: This is possible. But for versioning could be easier overwriting images only. My idea is, that some darker theme need some darker ikons and lighter theme some lighter icons. View of the module can be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some kind of wrapper shape for your icons. Something like this:

```
  <img src="@Model.Path" alt="@Model.Alt">
```

And then, from your view call it e.g.

```
 @Display.IconWrapper(Path="SomePath",Alt="SomeAlt") //The filename should be IconWrapper.cshtml
```